# Convert trigger in SQLServer pattern for MySQL pattern

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger created in SQLServer, I wanted to convert it to MySQL pattern :

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualiza_estoque ON estoque_folha
FOR UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE estoque_folha
            SET ativo = 0
        WHERE quantidade = 0 AND ativo = 1

        UPDATE estoque_folha
            SET ativo = 1,
                espera = 0  
        WHERE espera = 1
    END
```

Can u guys help me ?
Thanks ;)

Comment: This looks so simple. do you know how to create trigger in MySQL?

Comment: Yeah, but I cant convert this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be this script

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualiza_estoque AFTER UPDATE ON estoque_folha 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        UPDATE estoque_folha
            SET ativo = 0
        WHERE quantidade = 0 AND ativo = 1

        UPDATE estoque_folha
            SET ativo = 1,
                espera = 0  
        WHERE espera = 1
END
```

*Please "Mark as Answer" if a post has answered the question*

Comment: I have a problem:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE estoque_folha
            SET ativo = 1,
                espera = 0  
' at line 6

Comment: @JVitor, there was a syntax error, I edited my answer. try it and let me know how it worked. I don't have MySQL so can not verify it.